# Passar parâmetro para route resource | Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

Estou desenvolvendo uma aplicação de controle de projetos. Cada projeto tem suas tarefas, ou seja, quando eu crio uma tarefa, ela precisa ser vinculada ao projeto. Estou usando o recurso do Laravel de Route resource. Quando passo o id do projeto para a rota, ele não identifica no momento de entrar no método store.

form de criação da tarefa:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="tarefa" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h4 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel"><i class="fa fa-edit"></i> Nova tarefa</h4>
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                </button>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <form action="{{ route('tasks.store', ['id' => $project->id]) }}" method="POST">
                    @csrf
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="name">Nome da tarefa</label>
                        <input name="name" type="text" class="form-control" id="name" placeholder="Nome">
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="description">Descrição da tarefa</label>
                        <textarea name="description" type="Description" class="form-control" id="description" placeholder="Descrição"></textarea>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="difficult">Dificuldade</label>
                        <select class="form-control" name="difficult">
                            <option value="0">- Selecione -</option>
                            <option value="1">Fácil</option>
                            <option value="2">Média</option>
                            <option value="3">Difícil</option>
                        </select>
                    </div>

                    <div class="modal-footer">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Sair</button>
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Cadastrar</button>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

método store da classe TaskController:

```
public function store(Request $request, $id)
{
    $request->merge([
       'project_id' => $id
    ]);
    Task::create($request->all());
    return back();
}
```

Mensagem de erro: 
`"Too few arguments to function App\Http\Controllers\TaskController::store(), 1 passed and exactly 2 expected"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Na documentação do Laravel [disponível aqui](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/controllers#resource-controllers), no controller não é exemplificado esse parâmetro  `Request $request` ela me parece ser transparente para os resource controllers.

Seu erro, basicamente, diz que você está passando apenas um parâmetro na url mas o metodo espera 2 parâmetros. Se você remover o  `Request $request`, o erro não desaparece?

Confira a documentação do Laravel para saber como criar a Task usando filtros ou outra coisa fora desse controller

EDIT: Outra solução e iditar seu arquivo de rota e passar o parâmetro lá

```
Route::get('/store/{id}', 'TaskController@store');
```

Comment: se eu fizer isto, fico sem passar parâmetro para o método Task::create(). Mas de qualquer forma, removi e passei, apenas para ver se ele capturava o id do projeto, mas também não capturou, a mensagem de erro agora foi Too few arguments to function App\Http\Controllers\TaskController::store(), 0 passed and exactly 1 expected

Comment: Qual nome do controller que esta public function store(Request $request, $id)? Nome dele é TaskController?

Comment: Sim, esse nome mesmo TaskController.

Comment: testa o edit da pergunta, vamos ver, se não resolver excluo a minha resposta para outro tentar ajudar vc

Comment: Show! Funcionou, só um detalhe, o método é POST e não GET. Mas agradeço a ajuda cara.

Comment: Amigo, creio que o store não tenha parâmetro id.. E no edit, o parâmetro é da tarefa... O id do projeto vai no formulário. Daí então tu pode validar esse id na TaskRequest ... da pra verificar se esse id existe na tabela projetos.  Tens que largar um select de todos os projetos no form...